# Script to find and replace text in a .csv doesn't work with "=$"

Tags: python

My simple find and replace python script should find the "find_str" text and replace it with empty. It seems to work for any text I enter except the string "=$" for some reason. Can anyone help with why this might be.

```
import re

# open your csv and read as a text string
with open('new.csv', 'r') as f:
    my_csv_text = f.read()

find_str = '=$'
replace_str = ' '




# substitute
new_csv_str = re.sub(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)



# open new file and save
new_csv_path = './my_new_csv.csv' 
with open(new_csv_path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_csv_str)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a special character within the regex world.

You have different choices:

1. Escape the `$`:

   `find_str = '=\$'`
2. Use simple string functions as you do not have any variation in your pattern (no `re` module needed, really):

   `my_csv_text.replace(find_str, replace_str, my_csv_text)`